# How to use HTTP method POST without changing URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, post

It is common to use HTTP method POST to send a form.

For example, if the form action is "/login",

the request would send to server, and the URL would be like "index/login".

However, I want to implement two things.

1. Use HTTP method POST without "form". I want to send my own message.
2. And without changing the URL after the AJAX

Thanks.

Update: reply to DvS

The studies I have researched use libraries like jQuery or AngularJS.

But I want to implement by pure javascript.(like XMLHTTPRequest)

And I don't know how to use "NOT A FORM" in AJAX.

Maybe there's some references I can study?

Thanks again.

Comment: Just use POST in an AJAX call. A form is not required. What do you mean by "without changing the URL after the AJAX"?

Comment: @DvS I have updated my description, thanks.

Comment: Use Google to find hundreds of  tutorials to learn how to use `XMLHTTPRequest`. Then, when you get stuck, come back here and ask a specific question, and people will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer in "You might need jQuery"

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var resp = request.responseText;
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

The server side is implemented by Node.js and express

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.post('/newindex', function(req, res){
  console.log("req received!");
  res.send('This is POST METHOD');
})

app.listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try jQuery's AJAX call**

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
 $("#id_of_button_to_submit").click(function(){
     $.ajax({url: "/login", success: function(result){
            //do things with your result
            $("#div1").html(result);
     }});
 });
```

Comment: Is there any implement ways which don't use libraries like jQuery?

Comment: there is, you can do it natively. however, is there a reason why not?

Answer (score -1):

Old post but I ran into this problem and it got to my search results, and I suspect that the cause is the same.

Basically don't use a form action and submit button. 
Then call the function using a regular button, or whatever else you want.

Seems like default form behavior for the submit button but without an action is HTTP GET to the current page, which runs and of course mucks everything up.